# ReentrantLock -> lockInterruptibly() won't check interrupt state sometimes?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Recently i've been refactoring my project with "ReentrantLock" to simplify the logic.

The general idea is:

1. the "main" runnable thread is running on its own
2. if everything is in order, the main thread will wait on a condition "nextStep"
3. when something wrong happened, the method "onCancel()" will be invoked by/in another thread, forcing main thread to throw an InterruptionExcpetion, so the shutdown will occur

After some tests, it turned out my own method:

```
doInterrupt();
```

never worked as expected: forcing main thread enter "InterruptedException" clause and quit the loop.

**UPDATE-2:**
i've added a "is-interrupted" debug message to all the output log lines, if turns out the interrupt state is "mysteriously" cleared by some one...

**UPDATE:**

The lock and condition methods:

```
     lock.lockInterruptibly();
     condition.await();
```

seemed not checking interrupt state SOMETIMES? .... The javadoc reads:

```
    ......
    If the current thread: 
    has its interrupted status set on entry to this method; or 
    is interrupted while acquiring the lock, 
    then InterruptedException is thrown and the current thread's interrupted status is cleared. 
    ......
```

from the log it could see something like:

```
    [action] waiting for completion...: 1  [is-interrupted:false]
    >> DEBUG ---> will begin next loop     [is-interrupted:false]
    [action] reset for next iteration: 2   [is-interrupted:false]
    [action] cancelling...                 [is-interrupted:false]
    >> DEBUG ---> will interrupt           [is-interrupted:false]
    >> DEBUG ---> check.                   [is-interrupted:true]
    [action] waiting for completion...: 2  [is-interrupted:false]
    >> DEBUG ---> will begin next loop     [is-interrupted:false]
    [action] reset for next iteration: 3   [is-interrupted:false]
    [action] waiting for completion...: 3  [is-interrupted:false]
    >> DEBUG ---> will begin next loop     [is-interrupted:false]
    [action] reset for next iteration: 4   [is-interrupted:false]
    [action] waiting for completion...: 4
    >> DEBUG ---> will begin next loop
    [action] reset for next iteration: 5
    [action] waiting for completion...: 5
    >> DEBUG ---> will begin next loop
    [action] reset for next iteration: 6
    ...... and so on until i == max
    [info] main process has reached a finish state.
```

which basically means the interrupt signal is lost or not processed somehow...

**Is there some better approach? or a fix of my code logic at least?



any multi-thread experts???**

Here's My Code:

```
public class SBCSTaskEngine extends GenericEngine<SBCSTask> implements XListener {
    private final ReentrantLock     lock       = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition         nextStep   = lock.newCondition();
    private volatile Thread         main       = null;
    // something else ...

    // it's a runnable "MAIN"
    @Override
    protected void run() {
        try {
            main = Thread.currentThread();
            // some setting up... x is between 1 ~ 10000
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
                lock.lockInterruptibly();
                // some work ...
                log("[action] waiting for completion...: " + i);
                // a very long wait (could be REALLY fast if task went south)
                nextStep.await();
                if (max == i) {
                    isNormalCompletion = true;
                } else {
                    log("[action] reset for next iteration:" + (i+1));
                    // some reset work...
                }
                lock.unlock();
            } // end of [for] loop
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log("[event] process stopped by singal.");
        } finally {
            try { lock.unlock(); } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
        }
        log("[info] main process has reached a finish state.");
    }

    private void doInterrupt() {
        log(">> DEBUG ---> will interrupt");
        if (main != null)
            main.interrupt();
            log(">> DEBUG ---> check.");
    }

   /**
    * implement: XListener(series)
    * instruct main process to enter cancel sequence
    *
    * known-issue: duplicate call? sync on method? wait for risk evaluation
    */
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        log("[action] cancelling...");
        doInterrupt();
    }

   /**
    * implement: XListener(series)
    * proceed the main thread to next loop
    *
    * known-issue: signal might occur before all "memebers" could await on the condition (happen-before?), just take the chance for now...
    */
   @Override
   private void doNotifyNextStep() {
       try {
           lock.lockInterruptibly();
           log(">> DEBUG ---> will begin next loop");
           nextStep.signalAll();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           doInterrupt();
       } finally {
           try { lock.unlock(); } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
       }
   }
} // end of [SBCSTaskEngine] class
```

More Info: Java version I used:

> ```
> java version "1.6.0_26"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
> ```

Comment: Try to make all the fields final (lock, nextStep and main)

Comment: orionll << why ? can you explain ? shouldn't the Sync implementation inside the ReentrantLock does the work?

Comment: It seems that there are some design issues in your code. Please, read the following guidelines:
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/VNA00-J.+Ensure+visibility+when+accessing+shared+primitive+variables
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/THI03-J.+Always+invoke+wait()+and+await()+methods+inside+a+loop

Comment: orionll << i've added the final, volatile to lock, condition and thread variables, still not working. i'm not modifying any varaiables, just invoking mehthods

Comment: I suspect the problem lies elsewhere in your code, because the posted code works in a limited test. Please post a SSCCE.

Comment: @Leemax, per my comment above, the code above works. The problem is likely to be how the different methods are being called, by which thread etc. From your posted code, we can't see how that is happening.

Comment: Please, put log(">> DEBUG ---> check."); in curly braces inside if statement

Comment: @hendalst: you are correct, after examine every methods, i found that one of methods didn't show up here (in the commented //some work) has "swallowed" the interrupt exception by accident.... after fixing, it works as expected now! great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After careful examine every single method used in the "process()", it turned out there's a method "swallowed" the InterruptionException by accident... 

With simply throw out the exception, the entire code/class works as expected now~~~

**HUGE thanks to "@hendalst" who commented in my post to make me revise all the possible interruption leakage... as you said: "the code above works", the root causing method is inside the comment area "//some work..." which i didn't post here...



and thanks to "@orionll" for the suggestion about coding principles**

Comment: Glad it's working. For the benefit of those running into similar issues in future, please edit this answer with details of what the specific cause was and how it was solved.